# this.fs.move requires permission when running generator

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am trying to do the following without requiring manual intervention when running a generator:

1. Clone a repo
2. Move a sub directory within it to one level above
3. Delete the original directory

Can anyone suggest any steps I can take to run this generator without a prompt?

I think I maybe running into async issues where `this.fs.move` is run at the same time as `this.fs.delete` after the generator has run?

Possibly related to [this](http://yeoman.io/authoring/file-system.html):

> As asynchronous APIs are harder to use, Yeoman provide a synchronous file-system API where every file gets written to an in-memory file system and are only written to disk once when Yeoman is done running.

This is the code I am using:

```
child_process.exec('git clone --depth 1 ' + aplugin.url + ' build/plugins/' + aplugin.directoryName + '-hassubdir', () => {
  del([
    'build/plugins/' + aplugin.directoryName + '/-hassubdir/readme.md',
    'build/plugins/' + aplugin.directoryName + '/-hassubdir/.git'
  ])
  .then(() => {
    this.fs.move('build/plugins/' + aplugin.directoryName + '-hassubdir/' + aplugin.directoryName, 'build/plugins/' + aplugin.directoryName);
    console.log(chalk.green('moved plugin dir to: build/plugins/' + aplugin.directoryName));
    this.fs.delete('build/plugins/' + aplugin.directoryName + '-hassubdir');
    console.log(chalk.green('deleted: build/plugins/' + aplugin.directoryName + '-hassubdir'));
  })
});
```

Then in my yeoman output in terminal:

```
conflict build/plugins/pluginname-hassubdir/pluginname
? Overwrite build/plugins/pluginname-hassubdir/pluginname? overwrite
    force build/plugins/pluginname-hassubdir/pluginname
   create build/plugins/pluginname-hassubdir/pluginname/pluginnamePlugin.php
   create build/plugins/pluginname/pluginnamePlugin.php
   create build/plugins/pluginname-hassubdir/pluginname/resources/icon.svg
   create build/plugins/pluginname/resources/icon.svg
   create build/plugins/pluginname-hassubdir/pluginname/variables/pluginnameVariable.php
   create build/plugins/pluginname/variables/pluginnameVariable.php
   create build/plugins/pluginname-hassubdir/pluginname/resources
   create build/plugins/pluginname-hassubdir/pluginname/variables
 conflict build/plugins/pluginname-hassubdir
? Overwrite build/plugins/pluginname-hassubdir? (ynaxH)
```